# PWA App open manifest.json instead of page when installed on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, progressive

I made an app in PWA and it was working perfectly but after a few days it started opening the manifest file instead of going into the app page every time I access the installed App. This only happens when accessing the app installed by Chrome, if you install it in Firefox it works normally.

[image]

My app: https://bortonaggio.com.br/app/

I've already tested the app through Google's Lighthouse and it doesn't give me any errors. According to it everything is normal.

Does anyone have any idea what this error could be? I haven't found anything similar on the internet in any forum.

Comment: I have the same problem !

I think the problem come from the startUrl but didn't manage to find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had an empty string for startUrl in my manifest. After I changed it to "/" it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `start_url` from `/` to `/index.html` and its working and doesn't show manifest.